# Choropleth map geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

How do I go about assigning a different color for a winner by county for an election with 3 candidates. All the examples I look up online have a gradient color scheme and I am not certain how to assign different colors for each candidate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to make a subplot for each candidate that stack on top of one another.

See https://towardsdatascience.com/create-categorical-choropleth-with-python-122da5ae6764 for an example of a choropleth made from categorical data.